# how to enable tab function inside <textarea> using taboveride plugin of jquery

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, textarea

How to use taboverride jquery plugin in html code so to make tab functional inside the textarea? I followed what was given on jquery.com, but it didn't help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
     NOTEPAD
    </title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.taboverride/4.0.0/jquery.taboverride.js">           </script>
 <script>
    $('textarea').tabOverride();
 </script>
 <style>
     body
     {
         p
     {
           font-size:20px;
     }
     }
    .bigbutton 
    { 
         width: 200px; 
     height : 50px;
         font-size:35px;
     background-color:blue; 
    } 
    div.size
    {
         width:1285px;
     height:530px;
         padding:5px;
         margin:0px;
         color:black;
     float:right;
         text-align:left;
     background-color:brown;"
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <p> TITLE:<input type="text" name="title" size="209" style="float:right"></p>
 <div class="size">
         <textarea rows="18" cols="84" style="font-size:25px;">
     </textarea>
 </div>
 <div style="float:right;">
     <input type="submit" value="RESET" name="reset" class="bigbutton">
         &nbsp&nbsp
     <input type="submit" value="SAVE"  name="save"  class="bigbutton">
 </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your jquery files not included properly.
2. you css code is not good.
   body
        {
            p
        {
              font-size:20px;
        }
        }

   background-color:brown;"

You don't need to include jquery here. Because I used taboverride javascript plugin.
Download the taboverride.min.js from github and use it from your local machine.
Github path: https://github.com/wjbryant/taboverride/blob/master/build/output/taboverride.min.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>NOTEPAD</title>
    <style>
        textarea {
            font-family: monospace;
        }
        p {
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .bigbutton {
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 35px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        div.size {
            width: 1285px;
            height: 530px;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 0px;
            color: black;
            float: right;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: brown;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>TITLE:
        <input type="text" name="title" size="209" style="float:right">
    </p>
    <div class="size">
        <textarea rows="18" cols="84" style="font-size:25px;">Try out Tab Override on this textarea element. Use the tab key to add a tab character. Use shift+tab to remove tabs. You can select multiple lines to shift them left and right.</textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <input type="submit" value="RESET" name="reset" class="bigbutton">&nbsp&nbsp
        <input type="submit" value="SAVE" name="save" class="bigbutton">
    </div>
    <script src="taboverride.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        tabOverride.set(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i used your code but its not working, i am still not able to use tab inside the textarea whenever i click tab button it skips the textarea and focuses the reset button.

Comment: download the taboverride.min.js from github and use it from your local machine. Github path : https://github.com/wjbryant/taboverride/blob/master/build/output/taboverride.min.js